# How might one create a system of election by lot (sortition) that is both secure and verifiable?

Tags: hash, rsa, random-number-generator, cryptocurrency, voting

I've been puzzling recently over [sortition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sortition), a democratic method of selection for public office which I find very fascinating. Basically, instead of choosing candidates like Hillary Clinton or Donald Trump through voting, under sortition citizens would be randomly selected to fill public offices (in which, under many models, they would then be FORCED to serve for some period of time). There are of course many nuances, but that is the general gist. It would be rather like jury duty in the modern United States.

One particular problem for which I haven't been able to find a fully-formed solution online is ensuring that the random selection is actually random (so that it statistically represents the full population, one of the goals of sortition when a large-enough body is selected, rather than representing special interests or folks who paid off the people in charge).

Let me be clear: I am not a cryptology expert by any means. Indeed, I am only in high school and have never taken a proper computer science course.

Nevertheless, I was wondering if anyone here had any ideas (phrased at a fairly elementary level) for how fraud in the random selection could be prevented. (EDIT: While, as pointed out in the comments below, you could just have blind-folded people pull the names out of a hat, that might not be enough to keep citizen confidence high given the high-stakes and temptation for bribery and other such shenanigans.)

I've been wondering if maybe there could be a connection to RSA public-key encryption, cryptographic hash functions or other one-way functions, Bitcoin, etc (all those are subjects I know at least a bit about). I'm thinking there'd need to be a way for everybody to verify that the sortition wasn't rigged in any way (perhaps through some sort of blockchain?). But the method of choosing (let's say it's a function of some sort) couldn't be too simple because it would probably also need to be difficult for anyone to predict in advance what input would map to a given output, right? (If a selected individual for a public office was an output but people could predict which inputs would lead to that individual getting selected, then the choice of inputs into the function might get rigged by special interests, right?)

And, also, if you're utilizing a fully determinate mathematical function that would be, of course, not truly random (although maybe that's okay - political pollsters don't do truly random sampling either in that sense, but no one really seems to mind). So there's that issue too -- what do we do when we say we want "random sampling" but also want to be able to verify that the sample wasn't tampered with? (I have heard of the topic of pseudo-random functions - is that related to this perhaps?) Perhaps randomness can be approximated well enough [by introducing real-world data observations that are somewhat unpredictable](https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-36311668)?

Sorry for the length and it could be that these are fairly elementary questions (or maybe they are in fact very hard questions, I have no idea). I sincerely thank anyone who responds with any thoughts they may have on any aspects of this question.

One last thing: If there is a potential solution to this question that involves basic prime number/modulus RSA stuff, that would be really awesome -- since that's one of the few crytology concepts I actually sort of know. :) I don't really care at this point if potential solutions would actually work out in the super-complicated real world. I'm more concerned with finding something that's superficially plausible given the very elementary knowledge of cryptology I currently possess (e.g., basic RSA). Once I get more advanced I could then come back and refine everything.

Comment: It would be trivial to devise a fair system to select people at random to fill governmental positions; not so trivial to have a WORKING government staffed by draftees who will actuate the Peter Principal in polynomial time.

Comment: The answer to your question is in your question, you would select people by lottery drawing, the same way soldiers are selected for service. Put all the names in a big drum, spin it around and have blindfolded people draw the names out of the drum. As random as you are going to get in this world.

Comment: I think you would enjoy reading the [Algorand paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.01341v9).  The authors design a _cryptographic sortition_ protocol, and then use this protocol to elect a verification committee at random from the full membership in such a way that nobody is able to predict in advance who will be selected.  And, in a really clever twist, the protocol lets each committee member learn of their selection _secretly_ but in a way that they can later reveal themselves and _prove_ that they were indeed selected.

Comment: @kiwidrew, thanks so much!! I actually had found the Algorand white paper through Google searches but didn't really know whether it was related to what I was looking for. But with your little explanation I can probably do a more detailed read and maybe find some insight there.

Comment: Just to clarify, @kiwidrew: Would the verification committee be analogous to the chosen political officials in my sortition set-up, or would the verification committee only be analogous to some separate body that verified the political officials who were chosen? (What's the significance of a "VERIFICATION" committee, in other words? I hope you see what I'm getting at)

Comment: @kiwidrew, would this make sense? ... 1. Some number (doesn't matter) is centrally chosen as the seed -- this is publicized (future seeds might be chosen based on the previous election). 2. The government creates a verifiable random function (or multiple functions??) using a private key and inputs the public seed, causing selections to occur randomly of citizens. 3. The selections are immediately published with proofs that allow anyone to verify, using the public seed, that the hash function worked properly and wasn't tampered with. I'm still a little uncertain though... :(

Comment: I would think that the major challenge is actually getting consensus on the membership list:  all of the parties to the protocol must (at the very least) agree on *who* is eligible to be selected.  In a typical democracy, this function is performed by a government department which is responsible for maintaining the electoral roll;  citizens that wish to participate in the democratic process (i.e. voting) need to prove their eligibility to this department in order to be added to the electoral roll.  But what if there is no centralized authority?  :)

Comment: @kiwidrew, good point! I'd sort of brushed that aside, convincing myself that the government taking care of voter roll centralization wouldn't be any worse than the current system that uses that method. But it definitely left me quite uneasy, since it meant that malicious actors (within the government, or corporations, or foreign spy agencies, etc.) might find it easy to gain control -- to some extent the problem the U.S. is currently worried about with purported Russian "meddling."

Comment: @kiwidrew, maybe the insights from Algorand could actually help with a new, decentralized method of "voter" (really, candidate) registration... That seems to be what you're suggesting. *Hmm, on second thought though I feel like I am satisfied for now with having the government take care of citizen rolls. So the real question remains designing a secure drawing that is actually random from the citizen roll.*

Comment: @Will:  A secure random lottery drawing protocol can be designed if you have a trusted committee that will input all the potential candidates names into the lottery drawing "barrel" without any repeats. A fair "pool of candidates" so to speak. Then you have blindfolded people draw the names out IN PUBLIC VIEW so that there can be no cheating. These would be the four minimum requirements for a fair and random protocol. Public key cryptography has nothing to do with this basic process.

Comment: @WilliamHird, all good points. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to try to answer a more modest version of your question.

*Imagine that the Dishonest Society, a small club of 100 members, needs to take care of an Arduous Task that will require 5 people to complete.  The members are lazy and so there are no volunteers.  The members also don't trust each other very much, so they want to use a _sortition_ protocol to elect a random committee to do the Arduous Task.*

Let's assume for the following that the members have all come to agreement on the membership list of their club:

$$
M = \{ M_1, M_2, \dots, M_{99}, M_{100} \}
$$

### A physical protocol

The intuition is that the members will collectively generate a random
number, and then each member will try to guess the number.  We'll rank
the members based on how close their guess was to the random number, and
select the 5 lowest-ranked members for the committee.

First we have to decide "how big" our numbers will be.  We are going to
have 100 guesses, so let's pick the range 0 through 8190, which should be enough. All of our calculations will be done *modulo 8191*.  Because 8191 is $2^{13}-1$, a Mersenne prime, we are actually working in the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{8191}$ -- it will come in handy later when we look at the cryptographic protocol.

Now obviously we need the members to commit to their guesses *before* we generate the random number, so each member $M_i$ secretly makes a guess $g_i \in \mathbb{F}_{8191}$.  We don't trust the members to be honest,
so we'll ask them to put their guess inside a sealed envelope and write
their name $<M_i>$ on the outside.  Once all the members have prepared
their guesses, we put all of the envelopes in a box and lock it.  If a
member tries to cheat by writing down a nonsense guess, we'll find out
later when opening the envelopes.  (And if a member tries to put someone
else's name on his envelope, we assume someone will catch him when he
attempts to put it in the box.)

Next the members need to generate a random number.  $\mathbb{F}_{8191}$
is fairly large, so dice would be impractical.  Instead we will ask each
member $M_i$ to pick a random number $r_i \in \mathbb{F}_{8191}$.  Then
we have them write $r_i$ on a slip of paper and toss it into a hat.  Once
all members have put their random numbers in the hat, we can sum them up
to get a truly random number that no member can influence:

$$
r = \sum_{i=1}^{100} r_i \pmod {8191}
$$

It is easy to see that as long as at least one member was honest and selected their $r_i$ at random then the result $r$ is also random.  It
is also easy to see that none of the members knew anything about what
$r$ would be at the time that they made their guesses $g_i$.  And they
can't go back and change their guess, because it's in a sealed envelope
inside a locked box.

Now we can open the box with the guesses and calculate each member's
ranking based on how close their guess $g_i$ was to the chosen number $r$:

$$
rank(M_i) = r - g_i \pmod {8191}
$$

The committee for the Arduous Task can now be formed by choosing the 5 lowest-ranked members.  Ties can be broken by a roll of the dice.

### A cryptographic protocol

Assuming that all of the players can communicate with each other over a secure authenticated channels (standard in the multiparty computation literature) we can transform this physical voting protocol into a cryptographic protocol:

1. $M_i$ makes a random guess $g_i \in \mathbb{F}_{8191}$.
2. $M_i$ broadcasts a commitment $Com(g_i)$.
3. Wait until every $M_i$ has broadcast their commitment.
4. $M_i$ picks a random number $r_i \in \mathbb{F}_{8191}$.
5. $M_i$ sends each $M_j$ an additive share $[r_i]_j$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^{100} [r_i]_j = r_i$.
6. $M_i$ broadcasts $r'_i = \sum_{j=1}^{100} [r_j]_i$ and $g_i = Open(g_i)$.
7. Each player can now calculate the ranking of every other player as:

$$
rank(M_i) = g_i - \sum_{i=1}^{100} r'_i
$$

We use a commitment scheme to force each player to select their $g_i$ before they have received *any* information about $r$.  Because the
commitment hides $g_i$ until the openings are broadcast, the players
must select their $r_i$ before they have any information about the
other players' choices of $g_i$.

We use a secret sharing scheme so that no player (or coalition of players) has enough information to determine the $r_i$ of any other player, and so
this allows all of the players to send their $[r_i]_j$ shares to each
other simultaneously.

In the real world we'd want to also use a linear message authentication
code to *verify* each of the $[r_i]_j$ shares;  otherwise a dishonest
player could lie about $r'_i$ in step 6.  We'd also want to consider a
dishonest player who aborts in step 6 (without sending his $r'_i$ or
his $Open(g_i)$) after learning enough information to determine that he would be one of the "losers".

**No fancy public key cryptography required!  :)**

Comment: Humans are [biased](https://scienceblogs.com/cognitivedaily/2007/02/05/is-17-the-most-random-number) in a random number selection between 1 and 100.

Comment: @kelalaka, the randomness might be biased but we can still assume that each player's value is chosen independently.  That should be enough for the outcome to be strongly random.  (Think of the modular sum as being like a randomness extractor.)

Comment: @kiwidrew: Simplicity is Beauty :-)